# How should I design the interaction between multiple c++/clr projects?

Tags: dll, c++-cli, static-libraries, clr

I have a few different projects that all get mixed and matched into different types of solutions.

For projects, I currently have

- EngineProj: c++, built as a .lib
- GameProj: c++, built as a .exe
- EditorProj: c++/clr, built as a .exe

For solutions, I currently have

- Game: c++, built with EngineProj and GameProj
- Editor: c++/clr, built with EngineProj and EditorProj

This has worked great for games. I have been able to make a few different game solutions that keep reusing the shared EngineProj.

The Editor solution has EditorProj build a .exe with a WindowsForm object called EditorForm. This is used to edit generic game data that is common for all game solutions.

Now, though, I want to be able to do the same thing for my Editor that I do with my games. I want to be able to make game specific versions of the Editor that reuse as much project setup and code as possible. Here is what I am working towards.

For projects, I am planning

- EngineProj: c++, built as a .lib
- GameCoreProj: c++, built as a .lib
- GameExeProj: c++, built as a .exe (a very thin and small project)
- EditorCoreProj: c++/clr, built as a .lib
- EditorGameExeProj: c++/clr, built as a .exe

For solutions, I am planning

- Game: c++, built with EngineProj, GameCoreProj, and GameExeProj
- GameEditor: c++/clr, built with EngineProj, GameCoreProj, EditorCoreProj, and EditorGameExeProj

I am having troubles getting my GameEditor solution to come together.

The idea is for EditorCoreProj to provide the same EditorForm that EditorProj did; only in a .lib instead. EditorGameExeProj would then build with GameCoreProj.lib and EditorCorProj.lib. EditorGameExeProj would support a new WindowsForm object that derives from EditorForm, but implements new features unique to the needs of GameCorProj.

Various forms of unresolved externals have been plaguing me for a couple days now.

It seems that my issues stem from the fact that EditorCoreProj is a c++/clr project.

I read many articles and tried many different approaches, but eventually I found some reading that suggested that making a .lib would never work. It sounds like c++/clr .libs are not supported.

So, then, I tried making EditorCoreProj build as a .dll. For hours, I tried to get EditorGameExeProj to import the .dll. I read that maybe I need to tag everything for export and import. That sounded like a lot of work, and so I started just making some test solutions. However, that continually resulted in unresolved externals, too.

I am pretty new to making a .dll; I have always preferred .libs. Maybe I am just encountering newb issues with .dlls. At this point though, I have spent a couple days trying to get this setup.

And so, finally, my question.

Am I headed in the right direction? Maybe there is something much easier I should be doing?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sticking to the plan, and got everything working. I don't know if there was a better route to take, but this does full-fill all of my needs.